# How to use not English keybord layout in Qt Creator for Linux

Tags: linux, qt, utf-8, localization, qt-creator

My Ubuntu in English and installed QtCreator too. But I using Cyrillic keyboard layout as well. It's **impossible** for me **to type not English text** in Qt Creator code editor or Qt Designer. If I set the encoding UTF-8 at editor settings, then encoding is reset to 'system'. Here is my locale:

```
maxim@maxim-VirtualBox:~$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Qt Library version 5.2.1. Qt Creator version 3.0.1 
 What can I do to use Cyrillic keyboard layout too?

Comment: This seems to be related to a bug in Qt5.

https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,61617

It seems it has not been fixed yet.

Comment: What exactly happens when you type Cyrillic in the editor?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, Printed English.

Comment: It is not solution, but i use before they fix it. Close Qt Creator, change keyboard layout and then run Qt Creator again. Now you can print only Cyrillic text.

Comment: @dismine, yes it's true. But I use copy-paste from text-editor. It's faster.

Comment: Today i got update for Qt 5.2.1 in Ubuntu 14.04 that fixed this bug.